# Why isn't this javascript code working?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/LU3pE/

I want the function to make the arguments into a single string and return it. What have I done incorrectly?

```
function cooncc(divider, lastdiv){
    var returner;
    for (var i = 0; i < (arguments.length - 2); i++)
    {
        returner += arguments[i+2] + divider;
    }
    returner -= divider;
    returner += lastdiv + arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    return divider;
}
var output = cooncc(", ", ", and ", "Andy", "Becky", "Caitlin", "Dave", "Erica", "Fergus", "Gaby");
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + output + ".</h1>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing lots of things wrong. Here's a breakdown of what you need to fix:

1. You're returning `divider`! Change that to `returner`:

   ```
   return returner;
   ```
2. This line does not do what you expect:

   ```
   returner -= divider
   ```

   You cannot subtract strings from strings unless they're numbers, and that's why you get NaN (not-a-number) in the output.

   Try:

   ```
   returner = returner.substring(0,returner.lastIndexOf(divider));
   ```
3. You did not initialize `returner`. That will get you a "undefined" into your string. Initialize to the empty string:

   ```
   var returner = "";
   ```
4. You're adding the last string twice: once in the loop and then one last time with the last divider. Just stop the loop one earlier:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < (arguments.length - 3); i++)
   ```
5. Finally, think about what happens if you call it like this with only one string to concatenate: `cooncc(", ", ", and ", "Andy")`. You can solve this with a guard clause:

   ```
   if(arguments.length == 3) return arguments[2];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make the arguments into a single string? Do you mean you want this output?

```
, , and AndyBeckyCaitlinDaveEricaFergusGaby
```

If, yes, you can use this modification of your code:

```
function cooncc(divider, lastdiv){
    var returner = "";

    console.log(arguments.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        returner +=  arguments[i];  
    }

    return returner;
}
var output = cooncc(", ", ", and ", "Andy", "Becky", "Caitlin", "Dave", "Erica", "Fergus", "Gaby");
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + output + ".</h1>";
```

Oh, and if you change the last bit in your code from `return divider` to `return returner`, you get

```
NaN, and Gaby
```

although, I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sidestepping the question, but there are more elegant ways to do what you want to do:

```
var names = ["Andy", "Becky", "Caitlin", "Dave", "Erica", "Fergus", "Gaby"];
var divider = ', ';
var lastDivider = ' and ';

var concatNames = names.slice(0, -1).join(divider) +
                  lastDivider +
                  names[names.length - 1];

alert(concatNames);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

Initialize returner?

```
var returner = "";
```

And you can't do with strings:

```
returner -= divider
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize returner and you can't use -= with divider. If you put alert(returner) after the returner -= divider you get NaN back. try this fix.

```
function cooncc(divider, lastdiv){
    var returner = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < (arguments.length - 3); i++)
    {
        returner += arguments[i+2] + divider;
    }
    returner = returner.substring(0,returner.lastIndexOf(divider));
    returner += lastdiv + arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    return returner;
}
var output = cooncc(", ", ", and ", "Andy", "Becky", "Caitlin", "Dave", "Erica", "Fergus", "Gaby");
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + output + ".</h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needed major rewrite, here is working version:

```
function cooncc(){
    var arrWords = new Array();
    var divider = arguments[0];
    var lastdiv = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++)
    {
        var curWord = arguments[i];
        if (i == arguments.length - 1 && i > 2) {
            arrWords[arrWords.length - 1] += lastdiv + curWord;
        }
        else {
            arrWords.push(curWord);
        }
    }
    return arrWords.join(arguments[0]);
}
```

(no change in calling it)

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/LU3pE/1/